# What is this game similar to Quoridor?

Tags: identify-this-game

A friend of mine spoke about a game with rules a little bit similar to Quoridor but different.

The rules are the following:

- you have a board constituted of squares
- each player has a pawn which he has to move until the opposite side
- each player has several walls consisting of two square pieces
- each move a player can either:

  - move his pawn of one square
  - place a wall to a position on the board but always let an escape route for the opponent: unlike Quoridor the walls are placed *on the square* rather than between them.
- the game is won when the pawn reaches the opposite side

I'm curious if you know the name of this game.

**edit** :

It was actually qoridor but the rules was wrongly explained you can close the question as incorrect.

Comment: @XavierCombelle that sounds like someone mis-remembering, or mis-playing, quoridor, then.

Comment: You can delete the question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is like 4 years late but I think you're looking for a game called Got'em!

I haven't played either. But you can find it on [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/91831/got-em).

Answer (score -3):

the game you are looking for is called zigzag

Comment: This one? http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22266/zig-zag